# how can I create and execute a procedure that has just month and year with parameter in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have to create a procedure that get a month and a year and show all customers who bought in the month and the year specified. The procedure is done sucessfully, but when I execute it, the oracle show me the error: 01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month". I am from Brazil, so my variables are in portuguese:

```
/* I am brazilian, sorry my mistakes in english */

create or replace procedure P_data (p_data VENDA3.dt_venda%type)

IS

 data_venda VENDA3.dt_venda%type;
   nome CLIENTE3.nome_cliente%type;
  cursor cur_vendas3 is select V.dt_venda, C.nome_cliente from CLIENTE3 C, VENDA3 V where
 V.cliente_cd_cliente = C.cd_cliente and 
V.dt_venda = to_date(p_data,'MM/YYYY');

begin

 if cur_vendas3%isopen then
  close cur_vendas3;
   end if;
open cur_vendas3;

loop

   fetch cur_vendas3 into data_venda, nome;
  exit when cur_vendas3%notfound;
   dbms_output.put_line(data_venda ||'-'|| nome);

end loop;
close cur_vendas3; 

end;

exec P_dataCompra('19/01/2016'); -- This is the format year in Brazil
```

Comment: What is the type of VENDA3.dt_venda?

Comment: The type of p_data is the same of a field called dt_venda from table VENDA3.

Comment: what is the base type?  a number, a string, a ???

Comment: the base type is date.

Comment: Your procedure expets string with format 'MM/YYYY' on intput, and you passed '19/01/2016'. Try to pass '01/2016'

Comment: I tried it, but the error continues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_data(p_data IN VARCHAR2) IS
data_venda    VENDA3.dt_venda%TYPE;
nome          CLIENTE3.nome_cliente%TYPE;

CURSOR cur_vendas3  IS
    SELECT V.dt_venda, C.nome_cliente
      FROM CLIENTE3 C, VENDA3 V
     WHERE     V.cliente_cd_cliente = C.cd_cliente
           AND TO_CHAR(V.dt_venda, 'MM/YYYY') = p_data;
BEGIN
IF cur_vendas3%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE cur_vendas3;
END IF;

OPEN cur_vendas3;

LOOP
    FETCH cur_vendas3 INTO data_venda, nome;

    EXIT WHEN cur_vendas3%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(data_venda, 'DD/MM/YYYY') || '-' || nome);
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur_vendas3;
END;

exec P_dataCompra('01/2016');
```